# Get Assembly Name of Referencing Projects and Core

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-assembly

Let's say I have project A (as a core) and project B as the executing project(). I have them in the same solution and A references B and uses B for some calculating. I'm wondering how to query the assembly name in project A so I can execute the assembly of project B.

this is what i allready have:

```
    static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(args.Name);
        using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using(var fileStream = new FileStream(args.Name, FileMode.Open))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
            memoryStream.Write(bytes, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
            return Assembly.Load(bytes);
        }
    }
```

but it takes only the path for the project B... how can I add the path from the 'core' (A), to resolve it all together? the path for A is: C:\users\sources\projectB\ProjectCoreA

Comment: if you have them in the same solution and they reference each other, why do you want to load the assembly? it should "just work"

Comment: it doesnt work.. so its not the same project... it says: ok, i can load project b, i´ve found it. but when i click the button, that opens a method from froject a (in/thru project b) it says, it cant find the solution

Comment: In Solution Explorer find project A, right click on its References node, click Add Reference. On the left you have few options: Assemblies, Project, Shared Projects etc. Click on Project, find project B and select the check box on the left of it. Click OK.
Now you should have InteliSense with all classes in project B inside classes of A. Is that what you want?